# Dummit and Foote on Tensor Products of Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products

In its usual fashion, DF's Algebra treatment of tensor products is insufferably verbose. The problem I am working on asks me to show that $\Bbb{C} \otimes_\Bbb{R} \Bbb{C}$ and $\Bbb{C} \otimes_\Bbb{C} \Bbb{C}$ are $\Bbb{R}$-modules, but I am not even sure where to begin, and poring over the text hasn't helped much.

I think that most of my confusion lies in the fact that this "problem" doesn't seem very much like a problem at all. I mean, isn't $\Bbb{C}$ an $\Bbb{R}$-module and doesn't the tensor product construction guarantee that it is a module over whatever the factors are a module over. If so, then there is nothing to show, right? I'm confused.

Comment: $\Bbb{C}$ is an $\Bbb{R}$ module. But indeed, the construction automatically gives you more $\Bbb{R}$ modules.

Comment: I find DF has just the right amount of verbosity but what do I know?

Comment: Try showing that the operation $x\sum u_i \otimes v_i = \sum (xu_i) \otimes v_i$ gives an $\mathbb{R}$-module, where $x \in \mathbb{R}, u_i,v_i \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: If you would like to read a textbook that is less verbose, read Fulton and Harris Representation Theory

Comment: Is this a question or a rant? Firstly, no; in general if $R$ is a ring with $1$, $M$ is a right $R$-module and $N$ is a left $R$-module, then $M \otimes_R N$ is only guaranteed to be an abelian group. (Cf., the last paragraph of p. 363.) If $R$ is commutative as in the exercise, then one can endow $M$ with the standard $(R,R)$-bimodule structure and make $M \otimes_R N$ into a left $R$-module. (Cf., Cor. 12, p. 368). So a citation of this corollary seems sufficient.

Comment: Secondly, if this is Exercise 3 in section 10.4, I'll point out that the full problem statement is: "Show that $\mathbb{C} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C} \otimes_\mathbb{C} \mathbb{C}$ are both left $\mathbb{R}$-modules *but are not isomorphic as $\mathbb{R}$-modules*" (emphasis mine). So there is still something to show in this exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Quasicoherent mentioned in the comments above, it seems likely that the main part of the problem was the latter half.

I'd like to stress one point though. While it may be clear that both of these modules admit a left $\mathbb{R}$-module structure, I believe it is important that you pin down where it is coming from. It may surprise you. There are actually several ways these particular objects might acquire their module structures, and it is convenient that all the obvious ones coincide in this case.

You may find the following little exercise instructive: Show that $\mathbb{C} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$ admits two different 
left $\mathbb{C}$-module structures.

If you go on to study noncommutative algebraic structures, it can become quite a headache if you get fast and loose with where your actions are coming from.